# QTip2 Multiple Elements, Same Tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, qtip, qtip2

I have a page in which I dynamically create elements that need tooltips.

I've tried a few different approaches and looked online for some answers to no avail.

As of now, I have this:

```
var $links = $('a.link');
var len = $links.length;
for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
    var $ele = $($links[i]);
    $ele.qtip({
        id: 'editLink',
        overwrite: false,
        content: {
            text: $linkEditor,
            title: {
                text: 'Edit Link',
                button: true
            }
        },
        position: {
            my: 'top center',
            at: 'bottom center',
            viewport: $(window)
        },
        show: {
            event: 'mouseover',
            solo: true
        },
        hide: false,
        style: {classes: 'ui-tooltip-shadow ui-tooltip-red'}
    });
}
```

What I'm looking for is some way to have all of these elements use the exact same tooltip. I want them all to use the exact same content (in this case a single form) and reference the tooltip in the exact same way (by the tooltip element with id 'ui-tooltip-editLink').

With what I have, it currently creates the first tooltip correctly, but if I add a new element and reassign tooltips, it creates a whole new tooltip with a different id for the new element.

Does anyone know some way of accomplishing a multiple elements, same tooltip approach?

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out how to have one tooltip div be shared by many tooltip images if anyone finds it handy

```
 $(".tooltipBearing").qtip({
                            content: {  
                                text: $("#tooltipDiv").html()
                            }          
                      });
```

If you fail to put the **.html()** on there, you will see the shared tooltip show up once, and then when you activate it from another image, it will no longer work for the first one...

The **tooltipBearing** is a class set on some images in the page.

**tooltipDiv** is the ID of the div containing your tooltip content.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use `qtip` in dynamically created element, you need to include `qtip` during the element initialization.

e.g.

```
$('<div style="top:0px; left:0px; position:absolute;">abc123</div>').appendTo("body").qtip({content: "test"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly it looks like we need to clone the Tooltip element for each of the hover/click elements.

Craig mentions this in the GitHub issue: https://github.com/Craga89/qTip2/issues/173

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did. I attached the my tooltip on a unique element. And then all of my other elements that need the same tooltip will just trigger the unique element's tooltip display:

```
$('#unique-element').qtip({
  content: {text: 'My Tooltip'},
});

$('.other-elements').click(function(){
  $('#unique-element').qtip('show');
});
```

However, the all of your tooltips will be displayed in a fixed position. This was not a problem in my case because I was using the tooltip as modal. You will have to manage the tooltip position via cutom `event` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [the answer of user738048](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18218332/1051649), my working solution is like this:

```
$('[data-tooltipid]').each(function() {
    var ttid = $(this).data('tooltipid');
    $(this).qtip({
        content: {
            text: $('#'+ttid).html(),
        },
        position: {
            my: 'top left',
            at: 'bottom left',
            target: $(this)
        }
    }).removeAttr('href').removeAttr('onclick');
});
```

In my case, the id of the HTML element containing the text is taken from a `data-tooltipid` attribute; my `href` and `onclick` attributes are removed since they are obsoleted by the tooltip.